# Use config file to connect in different database sql server Application in .NET

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I have an application running in different cities. Each city has a server with different host name (IP ADDRESS). My Application connects to a database using the connectionString configuration from the config file like the sample below:

```
 <add name="SAC_NG.My.MySettings.db_SACConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db_SAC;Persist Security Info=True;User
```

As the system is running in different servers, I would like to select witch database I want to connect to use the system.

So the point is, instead of DataSouce = localhost I would like to select an option in the system before start running to select witch database I want to run the system.

Thanks.

Comment: As it's running on different servers, why not just update the connection string as part of your rollout process?

Comment: Sure. It is like that already, each city is configured to his host name server connection.

But I need to connect to different server. That's why I need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do as Mr. MarkAnswer suggests first:
Set up three connection strings with appropriate names that indicate to you which city they are for.

After that is done, you can have the user select the city (from a Dropdownlist or Radiobuttonlist  for instance) and store it in a `session` variable, and in accordance with that variable you can select which connection string to use.

(Or even better, you can store the name of the connection string in a variable and point to that variable on each instance the connection string is needed)

Answer (score 0):

Add ipaddress of your server  with instance of sql server to the data source..

```
example: 192.168.1.251\PISDEV
```

Create Different connection strings for different ip..

IN the code behind try to get the country and choose the connection based on the selected country..

(If you are not clear about ip and instance just run your sql server in server machine,connect to database engine,server name will be there when you connect,just copy it and pass it to datasource)..

Comment: Ok. I have this. It is already running, but each city I need to change the config file in order to connect to the right server.

But I need to connect any of them anytime, but I always need to change the ip address information inside the config file, I would like to do that thorough the application. before start running the system, I would like to choose which server I want to connect.

Comment: Give three different names for connection strings and call it inyour data layer or code behind...from you web page just prompt user to fill the country,based on the country select the connection string,No need to keep on changing in the web config file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connection string builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx). Configure your connection string without data source, initialize builder with it and then add selected server to the DataSource property.
I suppose you will use SqlConnectionStringBuilder.